# Is there any 2D Game Engine Better than Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've started libGDX programming a few months ago, and I've found many tutorials for **basics**. I've liked its cross-platform nature and ability to build Android, desktop and many other game versions at the same time - but when getting into intermediate and advanced features I found very few tutorials and documentations for it. I've spent many hours to figure out how to do some GUI and stage operations for instance.

I want to ask about the libGDX power in the Android gaming market? Is it the best 2D gaming engine currently, or is there better free alternative for gaming engine?

Comment: **primarily opinion based**. if you need anything more powerful than whatever java stuff, try some `C#`. You may do well with [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/)

Comment: You may see dermetfan tutorials, http://www.youtube.com/user/dermetfan/videos that might help you, anyway I like libgdx.

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to stand up for libgdx and say that also for intermediate and advanced topics, there *are* tutorials out there. May it be shaders, GUI, physics or input specific tasks.

If there is no 100% matching tutorial (which is usually the case for advanced topics in any framework), you can always try it yourself. LibGDX's API is very well documented in total and there is an extensive, but still growing [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki) tackling nearly every part of the API.

If you have really difficult problems, there is still the community. It has an active forum, questions on stackoverflow are also regularly answered and if nothing helps, there is still the active #libgdx chatroom on freenode IRC where you can find the main developers every day and get instant feedback on every kind of question.

I also always like to point to [Google Trends - LibGDX](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=libgdx) which shows the direction of this framework pretty well.

Comment: the main problem that I've faced is the GUI design examples with custom actors and scrollable panels.

Comment: interesting by 2014 LibGDX trends was heading to its peak... howeve, as of 2017 it shows a steep decline

Answer (score 5):

There are few 2D engines out there:

- [Corona SDK](http://coronalabs.com/) - easy to use, Lua
- [Marmalade](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/) - powerful, C++/Lua
- [Moai](http://getmoai.com/) - Lua
- [Love](https://love2d.org/) - Lua
- [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) - c++, c#, python (some people have used this for PC, Android and iOS development)
- ...

The list is not exhaustive...